# Animating Sprite Sheets in Cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm having some issues with animating my sprite sheet. I got this code before and it worked. I had 2 frames and my variable in my loop was only allowed to reach a values of 0 and 1 since the frame names were stickman0-568.png and stickman1-568.png. My frames weren't so good so I made a new sprite sheet with 3 frames in it, stickman0-568.png, stickman1-568.png, and stickman2-568.png. My .list file is called sickman-568.plist and the .png sprite sheet is stickman-568.png. I changed the loop so i could only reach a value of 2(0,1,2). When I run it now, it crashes, despite it working before when I only had 2 frames. Can anyone please give me suggestions as to what might have went wrong? Here's my code so you can see what I did:

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]) ) 
    {
        backGroundDesert = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"DesertMap.png"];
        backGroundDesert.position = ccp(backGroundDesert.textureRect.size.width/2, backGroundDesert.textureRect.size.height/2);
        [self addChild:backGroundDesert];
        [backGroundDesert runAction:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:100 position:ccp(-1400,0)]];

        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"stickman-568.plist"];
        CCSprite *mainGuy = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"stickman0-568.png"];
        mainGuy.position = ccp(40,backGroundDesert.textureRect.size.height/2);
        CCSpriteBatchNode *batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"stickman-568.png"];
        [batchNode addChild:mainGuy];
        [self addChild:batchNode];
        NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            CCSpriteFrame *frames = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"stickman%02d-568.png", i]];
            [animFrames addObject:frames];
        }
        CCAnimation *cape = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:animFrames delay:0.2f];
        [mainGuy runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:cape restoreOriginalFrame:NO]]];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeUnusedSpriteFrames];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When You Run the code the for loop create the images as below name

```
 stickman00-568.png
 stickman01-568.png
 stickman02-568.png
```

That is not images in your sources so only replace below line in your code of for loop. It work fine.

**Change the code as below.**

```
CCSpriteFrame *frames = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"stickman%d-568.png", i]];
```

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349388/cocos2d-sprite-repeat-animation-forever/19373921#19373921)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that wasn't the issue. I realized my textureFileName in the metadata section of my .plist file didn't match up with my code. Thanks, though.